# Bootup problems with iso

Tags: boot

I have copied the latest Ubuntu .iso to a CD and tried to boot directly from this CD.

After verifying that the setup in my PC does try to go to the CD reader first for booting (in fact I have set this at times to be the only boot device), I am unable to boot.

Is simply copying the .iso file to the CD not sufficient to make this a boot disk?

Comment: No, copying an iso file does not make a disk bootable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must burn the iso image specifically as an install cdrom, not as data cdrom.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is going on there, but be sure to "Burn" the ISO image to a fresh new disk, not just copy it. This is the only way a bootable disk is created. Other than that, it sounds like you have it right setting the machine to boot from cd-rom in your BIOS. Alternatively, you can boot Ubuntu from a USB stick as well.(Again, making sure to change the boot order in your BIOS accordingly.)